# Error handling in a Promise.all like flow in async/await syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have some issues to handle multiple rejections in "parallel".
How to handle rejection in a async function when we "await in parallel". 

 Here an example :

```
function in_2_sec(number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject('Error ' + number);
        }, 2000);
    }) 
}

async function f1() {
    try {
        let a = in_2_sec(3);
        let b = in_2_sec(30);
        return await a + await b; // awaiting in "parallel"
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
        return false;
    }
}

async function f2() {
    try {
        let a = await Promise.all([in_2_sec(3), in_2_sec(30)]);
        return a[0] + a[1];
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
        return false;
    }
}

// f1().then(console.log) // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
// f2().then(console.log) // Nice
```

`f1()` create a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` in node, because the second rejection (b) is not handled. 
`f2()` works perfectly, `Promise.all()` do the trick, but how to make a `f2()` with only async/await syntax, without `Promise.all()` ?

Comment: `await` "waits for the promise to resolve". In `f1`, you are waiting for each of the promises to resolve independently because you use `await` twice. Since you don't handle them at all, the behaviour is logical.

Comment: @Sebas: Indeed. I think the question is how to handle that logical behavior elegantly... :-)

Comment: @Sebas sure it's perfectly logical, and as T.J. Crowder said the question is about to handle this behavior without `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Wow, this question really threw me for a loop until I realized that the 2nd `await` is not executed at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `f2()` works perfectly, `Promise.all()` do the trick, but how to make a `f2()` with only async/await syntax, without `Promise.all()`?

Not at all. **Use `Promise.all`!** This is what it was made for. Don't think of `async`/`await` of replacing promises - you still are using them, it's only syntactic sugar for `then` calls. There is no syntactic replacement for `Promise.all`.

Of course it's also possible to re-implement the behaviour of `Promise.all` yourself (relying on the `Promise` constructor and `.then` primitives), but you really don't want to do that (there are too many pitfalls).

Comment: The issue with `Promise.all()` is that it only return a single `reject`. In other words, we do not get to handle all rejections should there be more than 1 promise that got rejected. Only the first rejection will be returned.

Comment: @NgHuiXiong If you want to handle all errors in parallel code, you have to handle the rejections individually on every promise before it is passed to `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing I can think of, and I don't like it, is to put unconditional calls to `catch` in the error path, probably with a utility function.

With these utility functions:

```
function noop() {
}

function markHandled(...promises) {
    promises.forEach(p => p && p.catch(noop));
}
```

It's:

```
async function f2() {
    let a, b;
    try {
        a = in_2_sec(3);
        b = in_2_sec(30);
        return await a + await b;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
        markHandled(a, b);
        return false;
    }
}
```

That way, we're explicitly ignoring rejections we don't care about, having caught the main error.

Example:

```js
function in_2_sec(number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject('Error ' + number);
        }, 2000);
    }) 
}

function noop() {
}

function markHandled(...promises) {
    promises.forEach(p => p && p.catch(noop));
}

async function f2() {
    let a, b;
    try {
        a = in_2_sec(3);
        b = in_2_sec(30);
        return await a + await b;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
        markHandled(a, b);
        return false;
    }
}

f2().then(console.log);
```

Comment: Didn't even think about it. Thanks. I'm don't sure that there is a very more elegant way. I'll stick with `Promise.all` for now.

Comment: @Smirow: Yeah. There's been [some talk](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-about-awaiting-arrays) about adding to `await` to handle things like this.